# Add vertical lines to `ComplexPlot3D` at roots

Tags: plotting, complex, polynomials, visualization

I have a `Table` of 6 plots of polynomials of increasing degree, using `ComplexPlot3D`:

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
poly[z_] := Sum[k*z^k, {k, 1, n}]; 
Table[ComplexPlot3D[poly[z], {z, -1.5 - 1.5*I, 1.5 + 1.5*I}], {n, 1, 6}]
```

[image]

I would like to add a black vertical line passing through each root of the polynomials. You can kind of see where they are from the plots, but lines would be a helpful visualisation aid.

I can obtain the roots easily enough:

```
Table[{poly[z], Roots[poly[z] == 0, z]}, {n, 1, 6}]
```

But how do I convert the data provided by `Roots` into vertical lines? Ultimately, I want to be able to do this for polynomials of arbitrary degree, so a 'manual' solution isn't much help.

Thanks in advance, and stay safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's modify your definition for `poly[]`:

```
poly[n_, z_] := Sum[k*z^k, {k, 1, n}]
```

In general, it's a good idea to make all parameters of an expression the arguments of the corresponding function.

With that,

```
Table[Show[ComplexPlot3D[poly[n, z], {z, -1.5 - 1.5 I, 1.5 + 1.5 I}], 
           Graphics3D[InfiniteLine[#, {0, 0, 1}] & /@ 
                      PadRight[ReIm[z /. NSolve[poly[n, z], z]], {Automatic, 3}]]],
      {n, 1, 6}]
```

[image: complex plots of polynomials]

Comment: Many thanks @J.M., this works. Just FYI, the reason I didn't include `n` as a variable is that this is a table of 6 different polynomials in `z`. The table uses `n` to tell `poly` the order of the polynomial in each case. But the line issue is sorted, thank you.

Comment: It's still not a good idea to have `n` be global. What if you had assigned `n` to e.g. 6.1 many inputs ago and then forgot?

Comment: Or to use the function inside a `Manipulate` you need explicit arguments, e.g., `Manipulate[ Show[ ComplexPlot3D[poly[n, z], {z, -1.5 - 1.5 I, 1.5 + 1.5 I}, ClippingStyle -> None], Graphics3D[{Thick, InfiniteLine[#, {0, 0, 1}] & /@ PadRight[ReIm[z /. NSolve[poly[n, z], z]], {Automatic, 3}]}]], {{n, 3}, Range[6]}]`